# Add new header/footer on landing page with plugin

Tags: plugin-development, templates, footer

I need to call a custom header/footer from a plugin for a specific landing page. How can I do this? I know I can make a template in my theme and call it by supplying an argument to `get_header()`/`get_footer()`.

However, I want to supply my footer/header from a plugin instead, since I often put all content associated with a custom landing page in a plugin. I don't want to have a footer template in my theme for every landing page.

What is the best solution for this? I don't want to hide content with CSS.

Here is a gist of what my landingpage plugin basically looks like:

https://gist.github.com/kyotoprotokollet/8b6e3f978ce3bd237e359e98cca151f1

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the template WordPress will be using with the [`template_include`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/) filter. Like this:

```
add_filter ('template_include','wpse303537_plugin_template', 10,1);
function wpse303537_plugin_template ($template) {
  if (is_front_page)
    $template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/my-template.php';
  return $template;
  }
```

Alternatively, you can include an almost empty template for the landing page in your theme and fill it through the action hook in [`get_header`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/).

Comment: Thanks. However this just seems to replace the whole template right? I'm already replacing the main template with the page_template filter. I just want to call a specific footer or header but have it reside inside my plugin instead of the themes folder. 

Maybe I'm misunderstanding you?

Comment: Yes, that's what it does. Because you state that you want all content from the landing page in your plugin. If you already have a special template for this, go for the second option: have an empty `header.php` for that template and fill it through the hook from the plugin.